# Tesla coil RF line protection

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, tesla-coil

I'm making a modest Tesla coil powered by an automobile ignition coil. All the instructables online say that I must also protect my home's 120 volt AC mains with an RF line filter. Trouble is, no one says what current or voltage rating these filters should be. So far, my guess is that a 120 volt, 10 amp AC filter should be acceptable. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: This may not be an ideal project to start designing electronics with.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage rating of the filter needs to match your mains line voltage, 120V.

The current rating of the filter needs to be at least as high as the amount of current being drawn from the mains by the Tesla coil.